QueryDSL 5.1 (JPA), Hibernate 6.3 and Window Functions
Context: I want to find the next and previous Entity ID, according to a search criteria and an ordering.
Hibernate is now supporting Window Functions, such as RANK, in the SELECT Clause.
Following JPQL Query is a start
SELECT new StepperDTO(rank, count, lag, lead) FROM (SELECT p.id AS id, RANK() OVER() AS rank, COUNT(p.id) OVER() AS count, LAG(p.id) OVER() as lag, LEAD(p.id) OVER() AS lead FROM Person p) AS q WHERE q.id = :id

Instead of plain JPQL (with Spring Data), I would like to use a QueryDSL JPAQuery to produce a similar query. I will need more flexibility in the WHERE clause using a QueryDSL Predicate and will also need to specify the sorting over the window dynamically.
Is it doable with current QueryDSL Release? Is there a workaround? Or does it have to be implemented first by QueryDSL developpers if they are still active?
Thks
